# Can I use a nonbasic land that taps and gives me either a red or white mana if I only have red mana in my deck?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can I use a nonbasic land that taps and gives me either a red or white mana if I only have red mana in my deck?

Comment: What do you mean by "I only have red mana in my deck?"

Comment: My deck is only red and black and so I only have red and black land but I want to know if I can use a non basic land that taps and gives me either a red or white land to my mana pool even though I don't have any white lands

Comment: Is this a commander question?

Comment: @Kurtis It's a good idea to respond to comments that request clarification by editing the question itself. Basically, pretend that these comments don't exist and anything you write here could be wiped away at any moment.

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm pretty new to Magic. Do you think I could still use it and only take a red mana when I tap it?

Comment: It gives *either* red *or* white mana, as you say in your question. So, even if it was in a deck with both colors, you'd still choose just one. And it doesn't really matter. You can add white mana to your mana pool in a deck with only red and black cards; it's just less useful.

Comment: @Kurtis: you appear to think that the nonbasic land gives you a land of the type you tap it for? It doesn't.

Comment: @Kurtis If RemcoGerlich was right and you're confused about land vs mana, please have a look at the [basic rules](http://media.wizards.com/2014/docs/EN_M15_QckStrtBklt_LR_Crop.pdf) - they'll probably clear up a lot of things for you.

Comment: For example, compare: [Wind-Scarred Crag](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=wind-scarred+crag), which produces red or white mana, with [Arid Mesa](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=arid+mesa), which lets you search your library for a Mountain or Plains, which will provide red or white mana respectively.

Comment: Kurtis, I would echo @RemcoGerlich's question: what do (or did) you think happens when you tap a land for mana? Did you think it allowed you to pull a land card from your deck and put it into play? That's a very common misconception (so don't feel bad), but that's not how it works. If you did have that impression, I think that's the reason your question is confusing many people.

Comment: This site really needs a canonical "land is not mana" post, e.g. for people that think that Dark Ritual lets you search your library for three swamps and put them into play.

Comment: @Kevin I was actually just thinking the same thing, but I'm not sure how much it would help. I don't think it's very likely that a new user coming to ask a question like this would happen to find that other question first.

Comment: @GendoIkari, Sure, but it would save commenters time by letting them link to an excellent pre-prepared explanation, rather than having to rehash it on the fly every time.

Comment: Speaking of excellent, pre-prepared explanations, Jefromi linked to one a few comments up. The basic rulebook says *"Lands provide mana [...]."* and *"When you want to pay a mana cost, tap (turn sideways) the necessary lands on the battlefield. This shows that you’ve used those lands to produce mana."*

Answer (score 7):

### Yes, as long as you're not playing Commander

In normal decks, you can use whatever (format legal) cards you want in any combination. You can play a Plains in an all Red deck if you really want to, though it's probably a bad idea.

If you're playing [Commander](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Commander_%28format%29), there is an additional rule that says that cards must match the color identity of the commander. This means that your cards can't have any mana symbols anywhere on them that don't match one of your commander's colors. In this case, if your commander isn't at least partially white, then you can't use a land that could tap for white mana.

Comment: @Kurtis When someone writes an answer that satisfies your question, you can click on the check mark next to their name to accept it. This let's other users know that your question was answered. You can always come back and accept a different answer if someone writes a better one.

Comment: Nitpick: In commander you can't have a land with a "{T}: add {W}" ability , but you *can* have a land with a "{T}: add one mana of any colour" ability, even though both colloquially "can tap for white"

Comment: @Caleth the answer specifically refers to mana *symbols*, which accurately represents the Commander ruleset - whether a land *can* produce a certain type of mana isn't important, but the occurrance of mana symbols is.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the [basic rulebook](https://media.wizards.com/images/magic/resources/rules/EN_MTGM14_PrintedRulebook_LR.pdf), page 15 ("Building Your Own Deck"):

> You build [your deck] using whichever **Magic** cards you want. There are two rules: your deck must have at least 60 cards, and your deck can't have more than four copies of any single card (except for basic lands).

This only applies to "Constructed" games - the "Limited" format follows slightly different rules; also certain tournament formats may restrict cards to only come from certain sets, and may also ban or restrict specific cards, as per [the banned/restricted list](https://web.archive.org/web/20151004123057/http://archive.wizards.com:80/Magic/Magazine/Article.aspx?x=judge/resources/banned). However, outside of the Commander format there are no rules preventing you from including multi-colour lands unless they are specifically in one of those lists.

If you do include one of those lands, there are a few things to note:

1. It does exactly what it says on it - so if it says "T: Add W or R to your mana pool", then you may tap it to add *either* one white mana *or* one red mana to your mana pool. If your deck has no use for white mana, then you probably won't ever choose to do so, but there's nothing stopping you from doing so.
2. The land is not a basic land of any type (unless some card specifies otherwise). So even if it produces W/R mana, it is *not* a Plains *or* a Mountain (or an Island, Swamp or Forest).
3. As stated above, since it is not a basic land you can not have more than four copies in your deck, or more than one copy if it is on the restricted list for the format you are playing.